# Android app crashes when I add a layout element with an id (BottomNavigationView)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

## EDIT: SOLVED (in the worst way possible)

Turns out my hard drive is corrupted. I'm sorry for wasting your time.

---

I'm currently running into a  error. When coding yesterday, everything worked and went smoothly. Now, all of a sudden, my app crashes for some reason.

Whenever I add a layout element with an id, say:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/newButton"/>
```

the app crashes on run.

However, if I remove the ID, so that the layout code would be something like:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

the app runs normally.

This is the logCat error I get:

```
2020-08-04 14:33:14.994 17775-17775/com.example.cloooset E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.cloooset, PID: 17775
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cloooset/com.simonbergmark.cloooset.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.example.cloooset:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #8 in com.example.cloooset:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3632)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3784)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2270)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8125)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.example.cloooset:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #8 in com.example.cloooset:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.example.cloooset:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.simonbergmark.cloooset.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:44)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7957)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7946)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3607)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3784)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2270)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8125)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
2020-08-04 14:33:14.995 17775-17775/com.example.cloooset E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setImportantForAccessibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setImportantForAccessibility(ViewCompat.java:1119)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView.<init>(BottomNavigationItemView.java:101)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView.<init>(BottomNavigationItemView.java:84)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView.<init>(BottomNavigationItemView.java:80)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView.getNewItem(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:589)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView.buildMenuView(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:521)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationPresenter.updateMenuView(BottomNavigationPresenter.java:67)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(BottomNavigationView.java:344)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:226)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:133)
            ... 28 more
```

This is the BottomNavigationView code:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

And this is MainActivity:44

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
```

Kindly help

Comment: What about a different `id` other than `newButton`?

Comment: @Saj sadly doesn't matter what ID i use. I've tried just spamming id's like "kdoskdla" and "ehsuejdaso" and so on but nothing works :/

Comment: @Saj thank you but I found the problem now. My harddrive was simply corrupted. Importing the project from github solved my issue. Thank you :)